Question on neutral and stochastic voting rules of variable size
I have a question regarding neutral and stochastic voting rules with domain of variable size.
THE SETUP
Let $N=\{1,2\}$ be a two player set, let $A_\tau=\{a_1,\dots,a_\tau\}$ be a finite alternative set, where $\tau\in\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,\dots\}$; let
\begin{gather}
    \mathcal{P}(A_\tau)=\bigl\{P\mid P=(P_i)_{i\in N}:P_i\text{ is voter $i$'s linear order over }A_\tau\bigr\}
\end{gather}
be the set of all linear order profiles on $A_\tau$, let
\begin{gather}
    \Delta(A_\tau)=\left\{\delta\in[0,1]^{A_\tau}\mid\sum_{x\in A_\tau}\delta(x)=1\right\}
\end{gather}
be the set of all lotteries over some alternative set $A_\tau$; and let
\begin{gather}
    \sigma:\bigcup_{\tau\in\mathbb{N}}\mathcal{P}(A_\tau)\to\bigcup_{\tau\in\mathbb{N}}\Delta(A_\tau)    
\end{gather}
be a voting rule that satisfies $\sigma(P)\in\Delta(A_\tau)$ for all numbers $\tau\in\mathbb{N}$ and all linear order profiles $P\in\mathcal{P}(A_\tau)$.
NEUTRALITY
Given any number $\tau\in\mathbb{N}$, let $M_\tau=\{\mu_\tau\in (A_\tau)^{A_\tau}\mid\mu_\tau\text{ is bijective}\}$ be the set of all permutations over the alternative set. Then, given any number $\tau\in\mathbb{N}$, any strict preference profile $P\in\mathcal{P}(A_\tau)$ and any permutation $\mu_\tau\in M_\tau$, let the strict preference profile $\mu_\tau P\in\mathcal{P}(A_\tau)$ satisfy, for all voters $i\in N$ and all alternatives $x,y\in A_\tau$, $\mu_\tau(x)\mu_\tau P_i\mu_\tau(y)$ if and only if $x P_iy$. Further, given any lottery $\delta\in\Delta(A_\tau)$ and any permutation $\mu_\tau\in M_\tau$, let $\mu_\tau\delta=(\delta(\mu_\tau(x)))_{x\in A_\tau}$.
A voting rule $\sigma$ is neutral if and only if it is independent of alternatives' labels. Formally, if and only if
\begin{gather}\label{eq.n}
    (\forall\tau\in\mathbb{N})(\forall P\in\mathcal{P}(A_\tau))(\forall\mu_\tau\in M_\tau)[\mu_\tau\sigma(P)=\sigma(\mu_\tau P)]
\end{gather}
THE QUESTION
Consider any neutral voting rule $\sigma$. Now, let $A=\{x,y\}$ and $A'=\{w,z\}$ be two sets of two alternatives each. Further, let $P=(P_i)_{i\in N}$ be a linear order profile on $A$ such that $xP_1y$ and $yP_2x$, and let $P'=(P'_i)_{i\in N}$ be a linear order profile on $A'$ such that $wP_1'z$ and $zP_1'w$. Namely, $P'$ is constructed from $P$ by re-naming $x$ to $w$ and $y$ to $z$.
Suppose that $(\sigma(P))(x)=(\sigma(P))(y)=1/2$. Then, by the neutrality axiom, the voting rule $\sigma$ is independent of alternatives’ labels. Thus, $(\sigma(P'))(w)=(\sigma(P))(x)=1/2$ and $(\sigma(P'))(z)=(\sigma(P))(y)=1/2$.
Let $A''=\{x_1,x_2,y\}$ be a set of three alternatives, and let $P''=(P''_i)_{i\in N}$ be a linear order profile on $A''$ such that $x_1P''_ix_2P''_1y$ and $yP''_2x_1P''_2x_2$. Namely, for both players $i\in N$, $P’’$ has been constructed from $P$ by replacing $x$ for $x_1P''_ix_2$. Suppose that $(\sigma(P''))(\{x_1,x_2\})=1/2$ and $(\sigma(P''))(y)=1/2$.
Then, is it also true that by the neutrality axiom, $(\sigma(P'))(w)=(\sigma(P''))(\{x_1,x_2\})=1/2$ and $(\sigma(P'))(z)=(\sigma(P''))(y)=1/2$?
